# @Contract, аннотация к циклу

Tags: java, intellij-idea, while

День добрый господа.

Есть кусочек:

```
while ((data != -1) || (data != 10)) {
   data = fis.read();
   sb.append((char) data);
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA выдает подсказку на условие цикла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могли бы вы дать простым языком пояснение к аннотации?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался почему подсвечивало... во первых, у меня было не верное условие, д.б.:

```
while ((data != -1) && (data != 10)) {
```

На сколько я понял, IDEA заранее определило, что второе условие никогда не выполнится, вот мне и выдала аннотацию об этом.